# Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

have a small problem in my function below .

i constantly getting this error : **Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined .**

trying to add this piece of code in my project that is related to wordpress menu.

here it is

```
t(function() {

            var e = t("#categories_navigation"),
                i = "click" == e.data("action") ? "click" : "mouseenter mouseleave",
                a = t("#categories_navigation_toggle");
            "click" == i && e.find("> ul > li:first-child").addClass("active"), a.on(i, function(a) {
                "click" == i && a.preventDefault(), t(this).toggleClass("opened"), e.toggleClass("opened")
            }), "click" == i && t(document).mouseup(function(t) {
                a.is(t.target) || e.is(t.target) || 0 !== e.has(t.target).length || !e.hasClass("opened") || (e.removeClass("opened"), a.removeClass("opened"))
            }), e.find(" > ul > li > a").on(i, function(a) {
                "click" == i && a.preventDefault();
                var n = t(this).parent(),
                    s = n.find(" > ul");
                t(" > ul > li > ul", e).css({
                    visibility: "hidden",
                    opacity: "0"
                }), s.css({
                    visibility: "visible",
                    opacity: "1"
                }), "click" == i && (t(" > ul > li", e).removeClass("active"), n.addClass("active"))
});
});
```

and this is my html codes

```
<div class="top-nav col">
<a href="#" title="categories" class="categories-menu-link col" id="categories_navigation_toggle"><?php _e(' Categories Menu '); ?></a> 
<nav class="categories-menu-navigation" id="categories_navigation" data-action="click" role="navigation">
<ul></ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

i should add that jquery file is attached to the page above all other js files . 
thanks in advance .

Comment: SO where is t defined? It is no where defined in that code. And last time I checked, jQuery does not use t.

Comment: Where is `t` defined? That's what the error means. The code you posted is a call to `t()` but there's no definition of it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the functions that you are calling with `t` I would guess that you are copy-pasting code from somewhere else. In the snippet you gave us, you are referencing a variable called `t`. The error message you are getting is because in your code you did not define what `t` is.

From looking at what you posted, my *best* guess is that `t` is supposed to be the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) variable, but that's traditionally this symbol: `$`.

There is another issue as well. The code after `a = t("#categories_navigation_toggle");` seems to be related to operating a menu like you said, but the syntax is quite wrong for a number of reasons. I think it'd be easier to help you phrase your question better than to try and fix your code without any additional context.

### Improving your question

If you did copy-paste code from somewhere, could you link to it so we can see the whole thing? I don't think you have the entire snippet posted in your question.

Also, please explain what you are trying to do with this code. Giving us details about what you're trying to do will be more helpful to us than just saying it doesn't work :)

Comment: thanks for your highly detailed answer kev . as you said i copy paste the code from elsewhere , but finally i got it working . thanks again .